Find the number of values of {$a,b,c,d$} $\in[1,2]$ for which the following two numbers are co-prime
Q) You are given that each of the variables $~a,b,c,d~$ is an element in $~\{1,2\}.~$ 
Find the number of distinct ordered $~4$-tuples $~(a,b,c,d)~$ such that the following two expressions represent relatively prime integers:
$[ ~2a^2 + 3b + 4c^2 + 5d ~]~$ and
$~[3a^2+b+2c^2 + 3d ~].$
My thoughts :
For the numbers {$a,b$} to be co-prime, the condition is $H.C.F.(a,b)=1$. Therefore according to my question, the numbers {$2a^{2}+3b+4c^{2}+5d$ , $3a^{2}+b+2c^{2}+3d$} will be co-prime iff and only iff $H.C.F.(2a^{2}+3b+4c^{2}+5d, 3a^{2}+b+2c^{2}+3d)=1$
Now I am thinking of finding the number of values of {$a,b,c,d$} by trial and error method.
For example:
When $a=b=c=d=1$ then ;
$2a^{2}+3b+4c^{2}+5d=14$ and $3a^{2}+b+2c^{2}+3d=9$
Now the numbers {$9,14$} are co-prime. Because $H.C.F.(9,14)=1$.
Therefore one condition is
{$a,b,c,d$}={$1,1,1,1$}
But if I try to find by taking such cases, then it will become a matter of $5$ days or more.
Is there any easier way to find the number of values of {$a,b,c,d$} $\in[1,2]$ for which the numbers $2a^{2}+3b+4c^{2}+5d$ and $3a^{2}+b+2c^{2}+3d$ will be co-prime?
Is the correct answer $\infty$ ?

What is the set $~I~?$  Also, do you intend that (for example) $~a \in {1,2},~$ or that $~a \in \Bbb{R}~$ and $~1 \leq a \leq 2~?$

Nope. Sorry. Actually $a,b,c,d$ are integers.

Edited. And keep one thing in mind that is $a,b,c,d$ each are either equal to $1$ or $2$

Since $~a,b,c,d~$ are each in $~{1,2},~$ there are only $~2^4~$ distinct ordered $~4$-tuples $~(a,b,c,d)~$ to consider.  While you could certainly look for analytical shortcuts, to eliminate some of the $~16~$ ordered $~4$-tuples, brute force computation is the fastest approach.  This is because the elements $~{1,2}~$ are so small.

I just wrote a simple Python program in a few minutes. It calculates all of the 16 cases, and 11 are co-prime. The pairs are (14, 9),(19, 12),(18, 15),(23, 18), (17, 10),(22, 13),(21, 16),(26, 19), (20, 18),(25, 21),(24, 24),(29, 27), (23, 19),(28, 22),(27, 25),(32, 28)

Can u show me the program in Python @SimonGoater

We analyze all possible ordered $4$-tuples where each variable is either $1$ or $2$. Since each variable has $2$ choices, there are $2^4 =16$ total combinations. These happen to be:

$(1,1,1,1)$
$(1,1,1,2)$
$(1,1,2,1)$
$(1,1,2,2)$
$(1,2,1,1)$
$(1,2,1,2)$
$(1,2,2,1)$
$(1,2,2,2)$
$(2,1,1,1)$
$(2,1,1,2)$
$(2,1,2,1)$
$(2,1,2,2)$
$(2,2,1,1)$
$(2,2,1,2)$
$(2,2,2,1)$
$(2,2,2,2)$

Now we have $$E1=2a^2+3b+4c^2+5d$$ $$E2=3a^2+b+2c^2+3d$$
Two numbers are relatively prime if their $gcd$ (greatest common divisor) is $1$. We compute $E1$ and $E2$ for each combination and check if $gcd(E1,E2)=1$. The acceptable combinations happen to be

$(1,1,1,1):E1=14,E2=9,gcd=1$
$(1,1,1,2):E1=19,E2=12,gcd=1$
$(1,1,2,1):E1=26,E2=15,gcd=1$
$(1,1,2,2):E1=31,E2=18,gcd=1$
$(1,2,1,1):E1=17,E2=10,gcd=1$
$(1,2,1,2):E1=22,E2=13,gcd=1$
$(1,2,2,1):E1=29,E2=16,gcd=1$
$(1,2,2,2):E1=34,E2=19,gcd=1$
$(2,1,1,2):E1=25,E2=21,gcd=1$
$(2,1,2,2):E1=37,E2=27,gcd=1$
$(2,2,1,1):E1=23,E2=19,gcd=1$

Resulting in $11$ distinct ordered $4$-tuples. Apologies as I can't find a faster way to solve this manually without brute forcing it. Feel free to reach out if you have questions!

Thank you very much @keixx
